# Ways to get ECB Directories buffer to udpate?

Tags: ecb

I see from a few posts that there's no mechanism for ECB to magically auto-update it's directories buffer, but I would have thought that when using the `ecb-create-source` and `ecb-delete-source` functions via the context menu, that the directories tree would get updated (it takes care to save the file right away).

Am I missing something?